# Как вывести похожие записи в детальной странице записи Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Задача: на странице записи вывести Похожие записи из категории, принадлежащей этой записи. Как это можно сделать? Где можно почитать мануал на эту тему?

Comment: Что такое "детальная страница записи"?

Comment: Это файл single.php

Answer (score 0):

Есть масса плагинов для этого: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=related+posts. С отбором по самыми разным критериям похожести и множеством др настроек.